# MongoWriteBatch:execute throws MongoCursorTimeoutException

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm performing bulk upserts to MongoDB using `MongoUpdateBatch`

```php
$batch = new \MongoUpdateBatch($collection, ['ordered' => false, 'wtimeout' => 500000]);
```

and occasionally get the following error:

```
Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds

Trace:
#8 MongoCursorTimeoutException in /var/app/current/src/Model/Campaign.php:286
#7 MongoWriteBatch:execute in /var/app/current/src/Model/Campaign.php:286
#6 ...
```

For what reason can `MongoWriteBatch:execute()` throw a `MongoCursorTimeoutException` and how can it be avoided?